# Show that the function $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ is convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I have to show that the function $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ is convex so I am thinking to demonstrate that the graph of the function lies above any of its tangent planes.But I want to prove it with linear algebra perspective.

To do this, i used the definition of a convex function in terms of its Hessian matrix. The Hessian matrix of a function with two variables is a $2 \times 2$ matrix that contains its second partial derivatives.

If the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite then the function is convex.Am I correct ?

To find the Hessian matrix of $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$, i need to compute its second partial derivatives:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(2x\right) \\
&= 2
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(2y\right) \\
&= 2
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(0\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(0\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Therefore, the Hessian matrix of $$f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$$ is:

$$H = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

To show that the Hessian matrix of $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ is positive semidefinite, i need to demonstrate that for any vector $x = [u, v]^T$, the quadratic form $x^T H x$ is non-negative:

\begin{align*}
x^T H x &= \begin{bmatrix} u & v \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u \ v \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 2u & 2v \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u \ v \end{bmatrix} \\
&= 2u^2 + 2v^2 \\
&= 2(x_1^2 + x_2^2)
\end{align*}

Since $x^T H x$ is equal to 2 times the sum of squares of $x$'s components, it is non-negative for any choice of $x$.

Therefore, the Hessian matrix of $f(x, y)$ is positive semidefinite and therefore the function is convex.Am I correct ?

Comment: Correct. $\phantom{.}$

Comment: Yes you are.___

Comment: What about showing that the two functions $(x,y)\to x^2$ and ... are convex first?! And well, the sum of two convex functions is convex.

Comment: @dan_fulea ok you mean separately to show that $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(y)= y^2$  are convex and thus their sum.This is what you are proposing ?

Comment: Yes, in this case the convexity of $(x,y)\to x^2$ is equivalent to the convexity of $x\to x^2$. Which can be shown by using analytic tools in one dimension, like the second derivative, slightly more elementary than building the $2\times 2$ Hessian matrix and looking if it is positive definite, or by simply showing algebraically the convexity by definition. Well, if we want to show that $f$ is "strictly" convex, then we need the Hessian.

Answer (score 1):

Great job! You are correct.

Another way to show positive semidefiniteness of the matrix is note that all the eigenvalues are nonnegative.

For a diagonal matrix, the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries. In your case, the eigenvalues are $2 \ge 0$.

Comment: or $\lambda^2 - \lambda \cdot Tr(H)+det(H)=0$.Using : $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{Tr(H)-\sqrt{Tr(H)^2 -4 det(H)} }{2}$ ,$\lambda_1 +\lambda_2 =Tr(A)$ ,$\lambda_1\lambda_2=det(A)$

Comment: I think you should state "positive *semi*-definite" instead of positive definite (or *positive* instead of non-negative right after, but that would be for strictly convex)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.